# How can I get layer type caffe in c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, blob, caffe

Is it possible get each

1) layer's type (e.g: Convolution,InnerProduct ,Data, etc)

2) the layer's top labels (e.g: ip1,ip2,conv1,conv2) in c++?

I searched the examples provided, but I couldn't find anything. currently I'm abel to get only the layers names by the following command

```
cout << "Layer name:" << "'" << net_->layer_names()[layer_index]
```

I'm searching for some command like **net_->layer_type**

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Layer` class has a public member function `virtual const char *type()` returning the layer type. Hence

```
cout << "Layer type: " << net_->layers()[layer_index]->type();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It worked. I was knowing the concept which you mentioned but was unable to implement (Call the function). Where is it mentioned how to call all the functions or tutorials for using "caffe" framework using c++. 
Thankyou for the help.

Comment: @GaneshMS I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you can find, e.g., here http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/annotated.html the list of classes in Caffe. Layer type is naturally known by `Layer` class, so checking its public member functions you can find the function needed for type. Similarly from `class Net` you find the public functions to get the vector of layers.